# Delete from table the records that are in #temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've created a #temp table in SQL containing duplicate records.

I would like to remove from my primary table all of the records contained in this temp table. I see samples to do this but they seem to all invovle selects, and I already have my select in the temp table.

Here's what it would look like in pseudocode:

```
DELETE FROM MyMainTable(unique and duplicate records) WHERE the record exists in #temp
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DELETE T
FROM MyMainTable T
INNER JOIN #temp ON T.id = #temp.id
```

You can also do:

```
DELETE T
FROM MyMainTable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM #temp 
                WHERE T.id = #temp.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

As global a level as your question:

If your temptable has the primary id's that the original had

```
Delete From Originaltable where primarykeyid in (select primarykeyid from temptable)
```

Comment: IMO you generally get better performance using an `EXISTS` with a `JOIN` than with an `IN`